# I cannot filter my dataframe by column values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to filter a dataframe by column values, but I do not get it. Let suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
Index Column1 Column2
1      path1   ['red']
2      path2   ['red' 'blue']
3      path3   ['blue']
```

My dataframe has exactly that format. I want to create a sub-dataframe with the rows containing only `['red']` in `Column2`. That would be just the first row.

What I tried so far, among other approaches, is:

```
classes = ['red']
df=df.loc[df['Column2'].isin(classes)]
```

But it does not work. I get this warning and just remains unchanged:

> FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
>     f = lambda x, y: htable.ismember_object(x, values)

How could it done correctly? Thanks.

Edit: I think I did not explain myself very good.

My data, for example `['red' 'blue']` does not have comma in the middle. Is type 'object'. I would like to filter the original dataframe in such a way, it shows the rows with the column 'Column2' containing, for example, `red`. In that case, it would show me rows `1` and `2`. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution is compare `set`s, advatage is ordering in sets with length > 1 is not important:

```
import ast
df['Column2'] = df['Column2'].str.replace(' ', ', ').apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

Alternative:

```
df['Column2'] = df['Column2'].fillna("''").str.findall(r"'(.+?)'")
```

---

```
classes = ['red']
df1 = df[~df.Column2.map(set(classes).isdisjoint)]
print (df1)

0      1   path1        [red]
1      2   path2  [red, blue]
```

Comment: Good to know I am not the only one who thought that OPs dataframe looks exactly the way he mentioned (no comma between red and blue). That is why I deleted my answer (I had assumed he made a typo) initially too. Anyway, I like this solution, couldnt think of that. Thanks. :)

Comment: Actually, that is the point! In my dataframe it does not have comma, is like I wrote initially (a mod edited my question putting the comma). What I have is data of type "object" and is like ['red' 'blue']. Thank you both, I am going to try such solutions and I will come back.

Comment: Do you also have it as ['red' 'blue'] and not [red blue] <- without quotes

Comment: @EAlvarado - Is possible use `df['Column2'] = df['Column2'].str.replace(' ', ', ').apply(ast.literal_eval)` before my solution?

Comment: @Ankur Sinha - They have quotes (single quote) @jezrael - I tried but I have the following error `ValueError: malformed node or string: nan`. I would like actually to keep the original format if possible.

Comment: I posted a solution now, check if it works for you.

Comment: @EAlvarado - How working `df['Column2'] = df['Column2'].str.findall(r"'(.+?)'")` ?

Comment: @jezrael - It does not work either, error: `'float' object is not iterable` (I think it's because my original data is actually bigger, with many other datatypes and interferes. Could it be?

Comment: @jezrael - BUT I tried your first approach, without any change in the original formating, and it seems to work. If `classes = ['red']`, it filters correctly and shows only the rows with contains `red`, also showing those with `['red' 'blue']`. The funny thing is, if `classes = ['red' 'blue]` it filters the original `df` with those rows containing any of both values (so, every row!). Is there a way to filter the original data so it shows only the rows containing just both? `['red' 'blue']`

Comment: This last thing is for the sake of knowledge. Your first answer works correctly in my case, I can mark your answer as correct!

Comment: @EAlvarado - Thank you, I rollback to first solution.

Comment: @jezrael - no! I mean the first approach you had before, it was correct. This one: `classes= ['red']` and `df1= df[~df.Column2.map(set(classes).isdisjoint)]`. That works fine :) Edit: Thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 1):

Your dataframe after reproducing exactly the same way:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Index'] = [1, 2, 3]
df['Column1'] = ['path1', 'path2', 'path3']
df['Column2'] = ['[\'red\']', '[\'red\' \'blue\']', '[\'blue\']']
```

Dataframe:

```
   Index Column1         Column2
0      1   path1         ['red']
1      2   path2  ['red' 'blue']
2      3   path3        ['blue']
```

---

## Possible Solution

You can try doing this by replacing `[`, `]` and `'`:

```
df['Column2'] = df['Column2'].str.replace('[', '')
df['Column2'] = df['Column2'].str.replace(']', '')
df['Column2'] = df['Column2'].str.replace('\'', '')
```

Now do:

```
classes = ['red']
df = df[df.Column2.str.contains(''.join(classes))]
```

Output:

```
   Index Column1   Column2
0      1   path1       red
1      2   path2  red blue
```